# Ruby on Rails Image Assets not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On my Application.html.erb page I have my navbar and footer so that they are shared accross all pages.  I am referencing images on this page as so

```
 src="assets/img-1.jpg"
```

and they appear but only on my index page "localhost:3000".

When I navigate to these pages:

```
localhost:3000/pages/contact
localhost:3000/pages/home         "index page"
localhost:3000/pages/portfolio
localhost:3000/pages/schedule
```

None of the images are being found. Here are is my route setup:

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do

    root 'pages#home'
    get "/pages/:page" => "pages#show"

 end
```

Here is my pages controller:

```
 class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def show
    if valid_page?
      render template: "pages/#{params[:page]}"
    else
      render file: "public/404.html", status: :not_found
    end
  end

 private
   def valid_page?
     File.exist?(Pathname.new(Rails.root + "app/views/pages/#   {params[:page]}.html.erb"))
   end

end
```

Again: images referenced as src="assets/img-1.jpg" on my application.html.erb are being found but only when I am in the index page "localhost:3000/", what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the rails assets helpers to reference your image

```
= image_tag 'img-1.jpg'
```

And please have a look [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets), it will save you many a headache.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing a `/`.

it will be `src="/assets/img-1.jpg"`.

**For production:**
make sure it's in the `/public` directory or you use `asset_path`. Otherwise you won't see it after you precompile the assets for production.